# Simple check in haskell

Tags: haskell

I am new to haskel.What would be a good way of doing something like this in haskell?

```
var1 = //can be true or false 
if(var1==true)
{
  //return someething
}
else
{
//
}
```

Comment: That is not how Haskell works... Haskell is a functional and declarative language.

Comment: You mean `return something` instead of `do something`?

Comment: yeah exactly , I simply want a check for whether var1 is true or false, and do the needful accordingly.

Comment: "do the needful"... the answer to the question probably depends on what the  needful is. Can you give an example of what you want to do/calculate in the 2 cases?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Haskell is a *functional* and *declarative* language. That means that usually that there is *not much "do something"*. There is more *calculate something and return it*.

That may look like nitpicking, but for instance in Haskell one cannot set a variable *twice*: once you assign it an *expression* (not per se a value)
, you cannot set it to a *different* value.

If you want to return something, you usually work with pattern matching. For instance:

```
f :: Bool -> String
f True = "Yes"
f False = "No"
```

This would be somewhat *equivalent* in Java/C#/... to:

```
public String f (boolean var1) {
    if(var1) {
        return "Yes";
    } else {
        return "No";
    }
}
```

Note that Haskell works *lazy* as well: if you return a function call or anything, you do *not* immediately evaluate that function call: a call is only evaluated if that is necessary.

A problem might arise how to do I/O. For that, there is the concept of an I/O [monad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_(functional_programming)). A monad is a functional programming technique that enforces a certain order of evaluation.

But *functional programming* thus requires a different "mindset" than *imperative programming*: you do not think of a program in terms of *commands* that are done one after another, but more in terms of composing functions together to generate output for a given input. Like usually a mathematician or physicist does. You compose for instance a function that, given the mass and the velocity of something, calculates the kinetic energy of that object.

Answer (score 3):

Haskell has if-then-else conditionals.

The closest code to yours I can write is something like this:

```
let var = length "hello" == 5
in if var then "ok" else "no"
```

Note that such conditional is more similar to C or Java's `var ? "ok" : "no"` expression than an `if()...` statement, but this is to be expected since Haskell is functional, so it has no "statements", only expressions.

Any Haskell tutorial should cover this. I'd recommend you read one, if you want to learn Haskell. Trying to convert idioms from other languages is a poor strategy.